# RegEx search for two pattern strings and cut what's between

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to write a little SQL Helper. I have a query like this stored in a string:

```
DECLARE @V1 INT

--ignore
DECLARE @V11 INT
DECLARE @V12 INT
--endignore

DECLARE @V2 INT

--ignore
SELECT * FROM SampleTable
INNER JOIN AnotherSampleTable
......
--endignore

SELECT * From Employee ORDER BY LastName
```

My helper method should cut everything what's between

```
--ignore
```

and

```
--endignore
```

The result string should look like:

```
DECLARE @V1 INT

DECLARE @V2 INT


SELECT * From Employee ORDER BY LastName
```

How can achieve my result with `RegEx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = @"
A
--ignore
B
--endignore
C";
        Regex regex = new Regex("\r\n--ignore.*?\r\n--endignore\r\n", 
                                RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string y = regex.Replace(x, "\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```

Note the use of [RegexOptions.Singleline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) so that `.` matches any character including `\n`.

I've used Windows line separators here, but you could make the carriage returns optional if you want to be able to cope with Unix separators. I wanted to make sure that the tokens were on their own lines to avoid any rogue references within the SQL, even if that's very unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still have a problem if there is more than one --ignore/--endignore block.

Comment: Oops, yes. Fixed now to make the `.*` reluctant.

Comment: What about Environment.NewLine ?

Comment: @Petar: That just determines the line separator for the current operating system - which may not be the line separator used in the file.

Comment: @Jon. Works fine now. Thanks you are my hero :-p

Comment: @Jon: True. I suppose the file is created on the same machine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Match your string agains "--ignore.+--endignore" and use string.replace to replace it with string.empty.

Comment: can you post a little code example if you don't mind. thank you.